# Using Mysql to count the number of grade

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table as shown below. I am trying to get the grade, the highest numbers achieved on that grade and the student that got that high number.

```
name    first_term_grade       number
std1       A                     10
std2       B                      8
std3       A                      6
std1       B                      1
std2       C                      3
std3       B                      2
std1       C                      0
std2       A                      1
std3       C                      2
```

The target result is shown below.

```
grade     max_numbers    studentname
A            10          std1
B             8          std2
C             3          std2 

I am using MySQL but can't find a way around this. Can someone please put me through.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you you are running a release less than SQL 8, then:

```
select sq.*, the_table.name as studentname from (
  select first_term_grade as grade, max(number) as max_numbers
  from the_table
  group by first_term_grade
) sq
join the_table on sq.grade = the_table.first_term_grade and sq.max_numbers = the_table.number
order by sq.grade
;

| grade | max_numbers | studentname |
| ----- | ----------- | ----------- |
| A     | 10          | std1        |
| B     | 8           | std2        |
| C     | 3           | std2        |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wF5Hv8FrDiXtPjVpyJGAUk/0)

Note that there could be ties, i.e. more than one student with the same grade and max_numbers.

```
| grade | max_numbers | studentname |
| ----- | ----------- | ----------- |
| A     | 10          | std1        |
| A     | 10          | std4        |
| B     | 8           | std2        |
| C     | 3           | std2        |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wF5Hv8FrDiXtPjVpyJGAUk/1)

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8+, `ROW_NUMBER()` makes this easy:

```
SELECT first_term_grade AS grade, number AS max_numbers, name AS studentname
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY first_term_grade ORDER BY number DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY grade;
```

The above query says to retain one row for each letter grade having the highest number value.